# Selecting unique cases

Tags: sas, uniqueidentifier

I have a dataset work.test1 that consists of 4 variables hhid (household id), pid (person id), pidlink (combination of hhid and pid) and bin (positive  or negative).

example data looks like this:

`obs    hhid   pid   pidlink     bin
1      10600   1    1060001      1
2      10600   1    1060001      1
3      10800   1    1080001      1
4      10800   1    1080001      1
5      10800   2    1080002      1
6      10800   2    1080002      2
7      12200   1    1220001      1
8      12200   1    1220001      2`

Now I want to create a dataset work.test2 that should only contain unique hhid that are either bin 2 (if there is a bin=2 in the household) or bin 1 (if there are no bin 2 in the household). If there are more than 1 bin=2, i would choose the first one. And if there are no bin 2 but there are more than 1 bin 1 i would chose the first one. The resulting dataset should only have unique hhid (single entry per household).

The resulting output should look like this:

`obs    hhid   pid   pidlink     bin
1      10600   1    1060001      1
2      10800   2    1080001      2
3      12200   1    1220001      2`

Thank you

Comment: please show how your output look like.

Comment: Thanks. I have added how the output should look like..i.e unique hhid cases where bin=2 takes precedence and in the absence of bin=2 then the first bin=1 will be selected. If there are 2 or more bin=2, then the first bin=2 will be selected. i hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as data and output shown a group by and max function should work and given me desired results.

> ```
> data  have(drop =obs);
>   input obs    hhid   pid   pidlink     bin;
>   datalines;
>   1      10600   1    1060001      1
>   2      10600   1    1060001      1
>   3      10800   1    1080001      1
>   4      10800   1    1080001      1
>   5      10800   2    1080002      1
>   6      10800   2    1080002      2
>   7      12200   1    1220001      1
>   8      12200   1    1220001      2
>   ;
> ```

```
  proc sql;
  select hhid, max(pid)  as pid, max(pidlink) as pidlink,  max(bin) as bin
  from have
  group by 1;
```

if you have more columns then it gets little tricky but you can do it but again you need more choice, otherwise you will more records. see the query below

> ```
> data  have(drop =obs);
>   input obs    hhid   pid   pidlink     bin anotherval1 abotherval2 $;
>   datalines;
>   1      10600   1    1060001      1 7 A
>   2      10600   1    1060001      1 8 B
>   3      10800   1    1080001      1 6 C
>   4      10800   1    1080001      1 8 D
>   5      10800   2    1080002      1 8 E
>   6      10800   2    1080002      2 9 F
>   7      12200   1    1220001      1 10 G
>   8      12200   1    1220001      2 7 H
>   ;
> ```

```
 proc sql;
 select * from have
 group by 1
 having pid= max(pid)  
 and  pidlink = max(pidlink)
 and bin =  max(bin) ;
```

if you want to have only distinct records with additional columns then

```
data have1;
set have;
val =_n_;
 run;

proc sql;
create table have2(drop =val) as
select * from 
(select * from have1
group by 1
having pid= max(pid)  
and  pidlink = max(pidlink)
and bin =  max(bin))a
group by hhid, pid, pid,bin  
having val=min(val);
```

Comment: if possible, please accept as solution, if it works for you

Comment: so now, lets say the originating dataset had more variables than just these, how would i keep those variables as well?

Comment: updated my answer,  please let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. The  updated code retains more records compared to the previous one. When I use your initial code I get the exact number of records i need but with only the 4 variables included...when I use your second code, I get more records than i need but I get all variables.

Comment: hhid and pid are same for below data , which one has to get more preference is the question, it may not appropriate to pick just  one. what do you think                                                                                                     
   10600   1    1060001      1 7 A
   10600   1    1060001      1 8 B

Comment: Yea I see. My approach was just to choose the first one that appears..in this case 1 10600 1 1060001 1 7 A. In this dataset, the idea is to have only 1 entry per household. If the household has bin= 2 that's the preference (over bin=1). if the household has more than 1  bin =1, it really doesnt matter which one is chosen but only 1 has to be chose coz they represent something that is different from bin=2 at household level. Hence I just choose the first one.

Comment: it can be easily done but significance of which last 2 columns have to picked and its significance will be lost

Comment: The significance of the last 2 columns wouldn't matter  as long as I have those two columns in the dataset. And as long as I have unique records for each household.

Comment: modified it to get distinct records

Comment: Thanks. there's some syntax errors..can you double check the parentheses and also the a after =max(bin)..then is pid supposed to be listed twice in the group by line?

Comment: Ok, it worked but it returns a comment that says 'the query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data' and it has roughly twice as many records.

Comment: we are having more columns than what we join on, that is why we see that comment